# Spring Mongo > How to get list AggregationOperations from Aggregation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have a function that receive an `Aggregation aggregation` as a param.

I would like to get all `AggregationOperation` from `aggregation`. Is there any way to do it?

```
public Aggregation newCustomAggregation(Aggregation aggregation, Criteria c) {
    // How to get list operation aggregation there?
    listOperation.push(Aggregation.match(c));
    return Aggregation
            .newAggregation(listOperations);
}
```

My purpose is new another `Aggregation` with my custom `MatchAggregation`.

Comment: How do you plan on using this `newCustomAggregation` function?

Comment: Hello chridam, I would like to use it for adding dynamic criteria to filter out the result when receiving it as a parameter (similar the way query.addCriteria(...myCriteria))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own custom aggregation implementation by subclassing the aggregation to access the protected operations field.

Something like

```
public class CustomAggregation extends Aggregation {
      List<AggregationOperation> getAggregationOperations() {
      return operations;
   }
}

public Aggregation newCustomAggregation(Aggregation aggregation, Criteria c) {
     CustomAggregation customAggregation = (CustomAggregation) aggregation;
     List<AggregationOperation> listOperations = customAggregation.getAggregationOperations();
     listOperations.add(Aggregation.match(c));
     return Aggregation .newAggregation(listOperations);
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The question is about getting the list of `AggregationOperation`s from an `Aggregation` instance. This solution gets a list of `AggregationOperation`s from a `CustomAggregation` instance only. For any other `Aggregation` it just throws a `ClassCastException`. I don't see much sense in that.

Comment: @jannis As you already noted there is no way to get `operations` field from `Aggregation` class. I have provided answer where op can subclass the `Aggregation`  class to access  `protected` `operations` field and expose the field through getter.  Let me know which part is still not clear.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not clear. I'm saying it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer: No, there's no GOOD way to do it.**

There is no 'easy' way of getting the `AggregationOperation` list from outside an `Aggregation` instance - [`operations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#operations) is a protected property of `Aggregation` class.

You could easily get it with reflection but such code would be fragile and expensive to maintain. Probably there's a good reason for this property to remain protected. You could ask about this in [Spring-MongoDB's JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO). I assume that there is an alternative approach to this.

You could of course change your method to take a collection of `AggregationOperation` as parameter but there's too liitle information in your post to say if this solution is feasible in your case.

Answer (score 2):

[Aggregation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#operations) has a property `operations` which will give you all applied operation in `Aggregation`.

```
 protected List<AggregationOperation>   allOperations = aggregation.operations ;
```

will give you all applied operations.

Comment: A) It's not static. B) It's protected.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Updated my answer

Comment: I saw but there is no method to get this property.. is there any way?

Comment: @TaiLe there is no need of a method, just call **aggregation.operations**